# How to pass data from node server(google sheet) to angular 9

Tags: node.js, excel, angular, api

When I pass the data from node server to front-end (angular 9), I faced the problem.
I made the server side using node and called data from google sheet api.
I tried to get the data from node server to angular and searched on google, but I couldn't find the result.

Here is my code of node server for calling data from googlesheet.

```
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1w0aEvmo8H-PPMQEaYWEfN8QSoeGgAKIb9gA0fr4V9VM');

async function accessSpreadSheet() {
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
    client_email: creds.client_email,
    private_key: creds.private_key,
  });

  await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0]; // or use doc.sheetsById[id]
  console.log(sheet.title);
  console.log(sheet.rowCount);
}

accessSpreadSheet();
```

In this case, I am not sure how can I pass data of server to angular front-end?

I followed to lots of stackoverflows, but couldn't get them.

Bellow links were I followed.

[How do I pass node.js server variables into my angular/html view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248394/how-do-i-pass-node-js-server-variables-into-my-angular-html-view)

[How to send JSON data from node to angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719179/how-to-send-json-data-from-node-to-angular-4)

[send data from node.js to angular with get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132631/send-data-from-node-js-to-angular-with-get)

Please let me know how can I get the data from server into my frontend?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node, the simplest way would be to create an express js api and return the information in an endpoint, though i recommend you learn some basic concepts about APIs and client\server http communication before you start your implementation

Comment: thanks for your advice.
yeah, i already used express and node for that.
my problem is to get data from it to my angular html.

Comment: it really depends on your frontend code. this the docs reference: https://angular.io/guide/http
you need to make an http request from your angular app